# Extract fields from JSON API response made with Blueprism

Tags: json, parsing, blueprism

I am using Blueprism to make an API Call. The response is a block of json. I need to extract the `conversationId` from:

```
{"results":[{"group":{"queueId":"aad701ad-56db-452e-8b70-aa9abd6046c7","mediaType":"email"},"data":[{"metric":"oWaiting","stats":{"count":1},"truncated":false,"observations":[{"observationDate":"2022-01-20T11:19:04.882Z","conversationId":"116b9f91-bf82-4275-9cdc-c405068b4cba","sessionId":"f97de11e-eb99-4781-ae13-33a9e5b6c3f0","routingPriority":0,"direction":"inbound","addressFrom":"e.mc@gmail.ie","addressTo":"info@gmail.ie","requestedRoutings":["Standard"]}]}]}]}
```

I am using this regex:

```
^.*? with conversationId ([a-f0-9]+)
```

but it is not working. Is this the best approach? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This is JSON, parse it to a JSON object and get the string with `json_obj["results"][0]["data"][0]["observations"][0]["conversationId"]`

Comment: What is the environment you are using?

Comment: I am using Blueprism to make an API call. I get the outputted json into a data item. The only next step I'd be familiar with is using regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Blueprism uses .Net framework

Comment: Don't use a regex to parse the JSON. JSON can be tricky and you will probably not get it right. Use existing code that can handle it. I don't know anything about Blueprism, but you could try searching for "blueprism parse JSON" or similar. I see other mentions of .NET, and surely the .NET framework has code that handles JSON for you.

Comment: Thank you @AndyLester I was able to find an object that parses and yes this is clearly a better option then Regex!

Comment: @Eoin2211 You're very welcome. Keep it in mind when you need to parse CSV or HTML or XML or URLs or pretty much anything.

Answer (score 2):

```
.*conversationId":"([^"]+)".*
```

will save the conversationId into capture group 1.

If you are using perl, you could do this:

```
s/.*conversationId":"([^"]+)".*/\1/
```

this works for your example but it's probably not going to scale well to different input JSON messages. As others have mentioned, the right way to do this is to parse the string into a native JSON object and then extract the field using it's methods.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm actually running via Blueprism and the regex doesn't seem to extract the value. It works on regex101 but not Blueprism? Blueprism uses .Net framework incase that's the issue

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I was going about this the wrong way. I should have been parsing the json and not trying to extract a particular string.

Blueprism has a json object which completes this very function.
https://digitalexchange.blueprism.com/dx/entry/3439/solution/utility---json